# Moving a top-level SVN repo folder into another repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We've several projects each as top-level folders in the same repo. It seems better to have multiple repos but even though all repos will be ourcompany.codesion.com/ you can't obviously pull things between repos without losing history.

Is there an easy solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by pull things without losing history ? Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do ?

Comment: The version history, I want to move repo1/myfolder to repo2.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to pull changes between projects, just keep them in a single repository then. The few disadvantages are that it will be more difficult to migrate specific projects offsite and it may be more difficult to back up individual projects, but these points really are minor.

Comment: There are several library projects, and application projects. It started as one app but now is growing, so this seemed better to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what could be the possible solution for your problem

1. take a remote or local dump of the repository. If you want to do remote dump you can use checkout [rsvndump](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/).
2. Use svndumpfilter and create a dump for particular dir you are talking about. [Here is blog which might help](http://blog.janjonas.net/2010-02-16/svndumpfilter-svndumpfilter2-extract-svn-paths-to-separated-repository)
3. Create a [new repository in codesion using the dump](http://codesion.com/benefits/faq.htm#uploadexisting) created in step two.